Failed to write genesis block: mismatching Fjord fork timestamp in database
When I run soneium testnet node, I got the following error. How can i solve.
I'm running this Soneium Node in VPS.
INFO [11-15|06:58:17.168] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 total=50 INFO [11-15|06:58:17.187] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory" INFO [11-15|06:58:17.210] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000 INFO [11-15|06:58:17.230] Initializing the KZG library             backend=gokzg INFO [11-15|06:58:18.908] Using pebble as the backing database INFO [11-15|06:58:18.908] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/data/optimism/geth/chaindata cache=16.00MiB handles=16 INFO [11-15|06:58:27.719] Opened ancient database                  database=/data/optimism/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain readonly=false INFO [11-15|06:58:28.194] State scheme set by user                 scheme=hash Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: mismatching Fjord fork timestamp in database (have timestamp 1730106000, want timestamp nil, rewindto timestamp 1730105999) Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: mismatching Fjord fork timestamp in database (have timestamp 1730106000, want timestamp nil, rewindto timestamp 1730105999)
